# How to open new activities inside fragment using different buttons?

Tags: java, android, button, fragment

I want my buttons to open new activities. I'm confused how to write the code.  I have only one button that can open a new activity.

Comment: Show what you have tried and got stuck.

Comment: I dont know how to show the codes. I new in stackoverflow. Just got an account

Comment: How to accept your answer? Sorry Im a newbie. And how to share my code when asking.

Comment: Welcome to SO ! To know how to accept the answer, see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers). To learn how to ask a good question, see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                     Bundle savedInstanceState) {
View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.profile, container, false);

Button newPage = (Button) v.findViewById(R.id.button2);
newPage.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), FirstActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
});

Button newPage1 = (Button) v.findViewById(R.id.button1);
newPage1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), SecondActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
});

Button newPage2 = (Button) v.findViewById(R.id.button3);
newPage2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), ThirdActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
});
return v;

}
```

**Another method (Switch and Case)**

```
public class MainActivity extends Fragment implements View.OnClickListener {

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.main_activity, container, false);

    Button button1 = (Button) v.findViewById(R.id.button1);
    button1.setOnClickListener(this);
    Button button2 = (Button) v.findViewById(R.id.button2);
    button2.setOnClickListener(this);
    Button button3 = (Button) v.findViewById(R.id.button3);
    button3.setOnClickListener(this);

    return v;
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    switch (v.getId()) {
        case R.id.button1:
           Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(),FirstActivity.class);
           startActivity(intent);
            break;
        case R.id.button2:
            // launch Activity2
            break;
        case R.id.button3:
            // launch Activity3
            break;
    }
}

}
```

Comment: Thank you. It worked. I thought id use the switch and case method.

Comment: You can have many method to do. `Switch and case` method is one of it.

Comment: Ah. Now I know. Thanks.

Comment: By the way, if I use switch and case method, what would be the code? Im still confused how to use it inside fragments